# Joomla Fatal Error issue

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I have updated the Joomla version (Joomla! 3.2.3), But When I edit any module, plugin or templage from the backend I get the following error :

```
    Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModulesViewModule::getForm() in /home/dnnrlign/public_html/layouts/joomla/edit/title_alias.php on line 12
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: What version where you updating from? Did the update complete successfully?

Comment: Now that you're on 3.2, you should try downloading Joomla 3.2 again, and unzipping the core files/folders. Could possibly fix the issue. Might be possible that you updated from an older build from the previous version

Comment: You could try setting error_reporting to 'maximum' in configuration.php, maybe there are other messages leading to this FATAL.